# \django_school\\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I downloaded pip and django with `python -m pip install django`, I also downloaded crycrs_forms but when I click to python manage.py runserver it crashes and doesn't run:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: as the error mentions, you are not running the manage.py command in right place. I think you are missing a step, maybe forgot to create the project first or go to the project directory.

Comment: Can you show your file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better location of packages and files and better management, you should use virtual environments.

1. First create a folder (*Django*) and open it in vscode.
2. Then use the following command in the terminal to create a new virtual environment (.venv)

   ```
   python -m venv .venv
   ```

   [image]
3. After the command is executed, select the virtual environment interpreter in the select interpreter panel

   [image]
4. Create a new terminal activation environment

   [image]
5. Install `django` using the command in the new terminal

   ```
   python -m pip install django
   ```

   [image]
6. Create a Django project

   ```
   django-admin startproject web_project .
   ```

   [image]
7. Create an empty development database

   ```
   python manage.py migrate
   ```

   [image]
8. To verify the Django project, make sure your virtual environment is **activated**, then start Django's development server using the command

   ```
   python manage.py runserver
   ```

   [image]